# How to write integers alongside pixels in the framebuffer, and then use the written integer to ignore the depth buffer

Tags: opengl

## What I want to do

I want to have a set triangles bleed through, or rather ignore the depth buffer, for another set triangles, but only if they have the same number.

## Problem (*optional reading*)

I do not know how to do this without introducing a ton of bubbles into the pipeline. Right now I have very high throughput because I can throw my geometry onto the GPU, tell it to render, and forget about it. However, if I have to keep toggling the state when drawing, I'm worried I'm going to tank my performance. Other people who have done what I've just said (doing a ton of draw calls and state changes) have much worse performance than me. This performance hit is also significantly worse on older hardware, where we are talking on order of 50 - 100+ times performance loss by doing it the state-change way.

Unfortunately this triangle bleeding scenario happens many thousands of times, so the state machine will be getting flooded with "draw triangles, depth off, draw triangles that bleed through, depth on, ...", except N times, where N can get large (N >= 1000).

A good way of imagining this is having a set of triangles `T_i`, and a set of triangles that bleed through `B_i` where `B_i` only bleeds through `T_i`, and `i` ranges from `0...1000+`. Note that if we are drawing `B_100`, then it should only bleed through `T_100`, not `T_99` or `T_101`.

My next thought is to draw all the triangles with their integer into one framebuffer (along with the integer), then draw the bleed through triangles into another framebuffer (also with the integer), and then merge these framebuffers together. I figure they will have the color, depth, and the integer, so I can hopefully merge them in the fragment shader.

Problem is, I have no idea how to write an integer alongside the `out vec4 fragColor` in the fragment shader.

## Questions (and in short)

This leaves me with two questions:

1. How do I write an integer into a framebuffer? Do I need to write to 4 separate texture framebuffers? (like one color/depth framebuffer texture, another integer framebuffer texture, and then double this so I can merge the pairs of framebuffers together at some point?)

To make this more clear, the algorithm would look like

1. Render all the 'could be bled from triangles', described above as set T_i,
   write colors and depth info into FB1, and write integers into FB2
2. Render all the 'bleeding' triangles, described above as set B_i,
   write colors and depth into FB3, and write integers to FB4
3. Bind the textures for FB1, FB2, FB3, FB4
4. Render each pixel by sampling the RGBA, depth, and integers
   from the appropriate texture and write those out into the
   final framebuffer

I would need to access the color and depth from the textures in the shader. I would also need to access the integer from the other texture. Then I can do the comparison and choose which pixel to write to the default framebuffer.

2. Is this idea possible? I assume if (1) is, then the answer is yes. Maybe another question could be whether there's a better way. I tried thinking of doing this with the stencil buffer but had no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is theoretically possible, but I can't speak as to its performance. You'll be reading and writing a whole lot of texels in a lot of textures for every program iteration.

Anyway to answer your questions:

1. A framebuffer can have multiple color attachments by using `glFramebufferTexture2D` with `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`, `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1`, etc. Each texture can then have its own internal format, in your example you probably want a regular RGB texture for your color output, and a second 1-integer only texture.
2. Your depth buffer is complicated, because you don't want to let OpenGL handle it as normal. If you want to take over the depth buffer, you probably want to attach it as yet another, float texture that you can check against or not your screen-space fragments.
3. If you have doubts about your shader, remember that you can bind the any number of textures as input samplers you program in code, and each color bind gets its own output value (your shader runs per-texel, so you output one value at a time). Make sure the format of your output is correct, ie `vec3`/`vec4` for the color buffer, `int` for your integer buffer and `float` for the float buffer.

And stencil buffers won't help you turn depth checking on or off in a single (possibly indirect) draw call. I can't visualize what your bleeding thing means, but it can probably help with that? Maybe? But definitely not conditional depth checking.